# Is there a name for the Cinnamon-Mint under-flavor?

Tags: flavor

I was experimenting with Italian Sodas, and added flavor shots that perfectly balanced the heat and cool flavors between Cinnamon and Menthol, and they canceled out. What remained was a previously unknown-to-me third flavor that was very, for the lack of a better word, clean tasting. It was refreshing, and also palate cleansing. I haven't experienced this flavor before, and was wondering if it had a name already. For the lack of another name, I've been calling it "Seng'd" (pronounced "Shinged", it just felt a name that fit the flavor, not much to the name really). But making up my own words, if there's' an existing one, is just silly since it doesn't help me talk about it.

Does this flavor have a legitimate name?

Comment: There are a couple of 'cinnamint' toothpastes out there, but it seems that it's also the name of a marijuana strain.

Comment: I would get many disappointed brownie eaters then if I went with that name.